# Can't start meteor app due to mongo exit

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to run the `angular2-boilerplate` example on my virtual machine, on which I have `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`, but the app can't start due to following error:

```
[[[[[ ~/Personal/myApp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
Unexpected mongo exit code 14. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 14. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 14. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 14. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 14. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.
Unspecified unrecoverable error. Exit was not clean
```

My meteor version is `1.4.2.3`

I tried the solutions proposed in other questions, but none of them worked.

`meteor reset`or `.meteor/local/db`

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 1001
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in the following way:

- reinstalled `mongodb`
- started defined the `MONGO_UR` when starting `meteor app`

  ```
  MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017 meteor
  ```

Comment: That's actually a good solution anyway. Part of the reason is that `meteor reset`, which is needed sometimes, also deletes everything from your database. Running a separate mongo server protects your data.

Answer (score 1):

One of the threads about Mongo exit code 14 suggests that you also need to delete the file:

```
/tmp/mongodb-<port>.sock
```

Which will normally be

```
/tmp/mongodb-3001.sock
```

if you are running on the default meteor port, 3000

Comment: I did that also, but it doesn't help.

Comment: You could try deteling ~/.meteor, and then run your app again - this will force Meteor to be reinstalled. Sometimes it gets confused

Comment: Still not working. At the start, `meteor` installs some stuff, after that I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved this problem by recreating the app on my home folder.